# Main Menu Color Change

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to target the header element of a drop down menu which I load in jfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DZLtm/16/

I am trying to get it so when you roll over nav ul li it show black instead of red. Here are the lines that I would have thought would do it.

```
nav ul li {float: right; width: 172px; height: 35px; background-color: red;}
nav ul li:hover > ul {display: block; text-align: left; background-color: black;}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">BUTTON IMAGE</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Accreditation Client Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Training Client Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Training Registration</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Guardian Tracking</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Can someone please tell me why nav ul li:hover wont work and what is > ul have to do with it. When I remove it it breaks the menu. Thank you Frank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `nav ul li:hover {
    background-color:black;
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/weissman258/DZLtm/17/

Comment: I could have sworn I did that... ugggggg I hate css :( thanks! That was it!

Comment: I made the change like you suggested. But the drop down menu is acting weird now. If you go here http://jsfiddle.net/DZLtm/20/ and then roll over the Buttom Image Here and down the menu it jumps. Do you know what could cause that? Thanks again!

Comment: I figured it out... I must of had something wrong with the css syntax for the images. Here is the final css for it:

Comment: Get rid of the `float` and `position` on `nav ul ul li`
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/weissman258/DZLtm/21/)

Comment: nav ul li {float: right; width: 172px; height: 35px; background-image:url(images/clt_login_butn.png);}
nav ul li:hover { background-image:url(images/clt_login_butn_on.png);}
nav ul li:hover > ul {display: block; text-align: left;}

Comment: Also if you want the text to change red, check out [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/weissman258/DZLtm/22/)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35960/discussion-between-grant-weiss-and-frank-g)

Comment: nope what you did is PERFECT!! Thank you for helping figure out what I did wrong!!